# Is the math used in this video(related to equilibrium constant in chemistry) sound?

Tags: probability

Sal Khan has a pretty neat video on the intuition behind the form of the equilibrium constant expression. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell  me if the probabilistic assumptions used in the video are mathematically sound.

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/reaction-rates/v/keq-intuition-mathy-and-not-necessary-to-progress#

EDIT: An alternate, slightly different video

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry/reaction-rates/v/keq-derivation-intuition-can-skip-bit-mathy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are mathematically sound.